# MongoDB grouping on Subdocument Query Performance on Large Dataset

Tags: mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a large collection in mongodb. It has around a million documents in that collection. But when i run aggregation pipeline on it, it takes almost 60 seconds to return unique values. I cant get any relevant solution to reduce the time for aggregation pipeline.
The ask I am trying to solve is get the distinct location objects from this entire collection. below is the sample document from the mongodb collection.

```
{
  "itemCode": "123456789",
  "description": "item description",
  "pack": 6,
  "uom": "LB",
  "locations": [
    {
      "vendNum": "1234567",
      "vendName": "vendor name",
      "vendOtltName": "vendor outlet name",
      "vendSAcc": "001",
      "supplyType": "D",
      "costArea": "1",
      "supplierCode": "",
      "supplierName": ""
      "zone": "30",
      "zoneName": "Denver",
    }
  ]
}
```

my collection has two indexes, one on "supplyType" field and the other one is a compound index on all fields in "location" sub document but group stage ignoring it seems.

my **mongoDB version is 6.0.11**

Thanks for the help.

I tried with the following aggregation query to fetch distinct locations from the entire collection.

````
[
  {
    $match:
      {
        "locations.supplyType": "D",
      },
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$locations",
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      costAreas: {
        $addToSet: {
          vendNum: "$locations.vendNum",
          vendOtltName:
            "$locations.vendOtltName",
          zone: "$locations.zone",
          zoneName: "$locations.zoneName",
          vendSAcc:
            "$locations.vendSAcc",
          costArea: "$locations.costArea",
        },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      costAreas: 1,
    },
  },
]```
````

Comment: When discussing performance, you need to clarify the threshold/requirement first. If 60s is "slow" to you, what time is acceptable? Besides, it would be more helpful if you also put your indexes and `explain` result here. I have tried to replicate a [simplified version of your scenario](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PkMpu3GBgCH) and seems all indexes are currently utilized.

Comment: Also, if you find yourself more often to work at `locations` level, consider storing them as individual documents instead of array entries and denormalize the common fields like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mI6rrEk-3Pt)